# Java for loop returning the same number multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop that is trying to extend an array by adding new array element that is double the previous value.
e.g.

starting at : array = {1}

ending at : array = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc}

Currently my for loop spits out an array like this : array = {1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16}
It puts the same number in twice for some reason.

Just see the variable "input" as 21

```
for (int i = 0; (nums[i] * 2) < input; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            nums = IncreaseArrayInt(nums, nums[(i)] * 2);
        }
        else 
        {
            nums = IncreaseArrayInt(nums, nums[(i - 1)] * 2);
        }
    }
```

Heres the function i used to extend the array:

```
static int[] IncreaseArrayInt(int[] oldArray, int insertValue)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.length + 1];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    
    newArray[oldArray.length] = insertValue;
    return (newArray);
}
```

Its very close to working as intended and hoping some can see the issue im missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
nums = IncreaseArrayInt(nums, nums[(i - 1)] * 2);
```

to:

```
nums = IncreaseArrayInt(nums, nums[(i)] * 2);
```

Comment: No prob :D @EvanO'R

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first two passes in the for loop both make insertValue 1 * 2.  you should get rid of the if else statement and just use `nums = IncreaseArrayInt(nums, nums[(i)] * 2);` for all of the possible values of i.